# "Find next" broken in pdflatex output in Skim on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: pdftex, pdf, mac

When loading into Skim a pdf document that was created using pdflatex, the "Find next" action (e.g., Cmd-G or clicking the right arrow in the find bar) works incorrectly.  In a document with tens of occurrences of a particular word, it will find the first few occurrences and then stop moving on to the next occurrence.  Searching backwards does seem to work.  This is super annoying for large documents :(

Preview is able to search the document just fine.

A bug has been filed in Skim, but the author appears to think this is a Mountain Lion issue.  I've added my own comments.  [link to the bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3553209&group_id=192583&atid=941981)

I suspect the issue has to do with a combination of the way that pdflatex is writing the pdf and the way that PDFkit (or whatever Skim is using) searches the document.

Has anyone else had this problem?  Does anyone have a suggestion to fix it?  (using dvi as an intermediary isn't really convenient in my case)

Comment: As described, this really doesn't sound like an issue for this site.  Can you pin-down the difference in the PDF between a document produced by pdflatex and one that works?  Without that, it's not going to be fixable at the tex level.

Comment: Not really, but I was hoping this might be the kind of place where someone would know enough about how latex produces pdfs that they might have some insight :-/